# Concatenate excluding 0,1 without commas

Tags: excel-formula

I am looking for a formula to concatenate cells only with numbers greater than 1.
If the cells have 0 or 1, they shouldn't be concatenated.

For example, `

```
if A1:E1 (1,1,2,0,3), then in H1= (32)`
If A1:E1 (0,0,0,1,2), then in H1 = (2)
If A1:E1 (0,2,2,1,2), then in H1 = (222)
if A1:E1 (0,0,0,1,1), then in H1 = ()
```

Without commas, please. Even though I used the function concatenation, it doesn't have to be that function. I just need a formula something similar. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the prettiest solution, but you could just use `IF` expressions:

```
=CONCATENATE(IF(A1 > 1, A1, ""),
             IF(B1 > 1, B1, ""),
             IF(C1 > 1, C1, ""),
             IF(D1 > 1, D1, ""),
             IF(E1 > 1, E1, ""))
```